# decorate __call__ with @staticmethod

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods, python-decorators

Why can't I make a class' __call__ method static using the @staticmethod decorator?

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return 'bar'

    @staticmethod
    def __call__():
        return '__call__'

print Foo.bar()
print Foo()
```

outputs

```
bar
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fabf93c89d0>
```

but I would expect it to output

```
bar
__call__
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to override `__call__` on the metaclass. The special methods defined in a class are for its instances, to change a class's special methods you need to change them in its class, i.e metaclass. (When you call `Foo()` usually the order is: `Meta.__call__()` --> `Foo.__new__()` --> `Foo.__init__()`, only if they return normally)

```
class Meta(type):
    @staticmethod 
    def __call__():
        return '__call__'


class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return 'bar'

print Foo()
#__call__
```

---

As you're trying to modify class instantiation, another way will be to override `__new__` on the class itself and return `__call__` from it(when `__new__` returns something other than an instance the `__init__` method is never called):

```
class Foo(object):

    def __new__(*args):
        #ignore the args 
        return '__call__'

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return 'bar'

print Foo()
#__call__
```

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up for me. What do you mean by `Meta.__call__()` --> `Foo.__new__()` --> `Foo.__init__()`?  Do the arrows mean "calls"?

Comment: @fragapanagos That's the order followed by Python when a class is instantiated. See: http://ideone.com/4gxeiN

Comment: Could the meta object be skipped by having the desired type inherit from `type`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out this problem after having searched for a while but not finding an answer. Then, as I was about to submit my Q&A post to share, I found this post in the list of similarly asked questions. Since I did the work and it may help others find this post in the future, I'm adding it here as an answer.

---

### QUESTION

Is it possible to make `__call__` a class method or static method which can be used to execute the same instance of functionality multiple times? For example:

```py
class MyClass:
  ...
  _phrase: str = None

  @classmethod
  def __call__(cls, phrase: str=None) -> str:
    ...
    if phrase is not None:
      ...# Implement a custom initialization and update
      cls._phrase = phrase

    elif (cls._phrase, phrase) == (None, None): 
      ...# Implement a default initialization
      cls._phrase = "Hello, world!"

    # Do any necessary work here

    return cls._phrase

print(MyClass())                  # Should print "Hello, world!" but prints address
                                  # <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000002069BC5BF70>

print(MyClass("Goodbye, y'all!")) # Should print "Goodbye, y'all!" but raises error
                                  # TypeError: MyClass() takes no arguments
```

---

### ANSWER

The short answer is to use `__new__` in place of `__init__` and `__call__`. `__new__` seems to have a couple important qualities which make it the best way to implement a static callable class. First, when `__new__` is implemented, any `__init__` or `__call__` implementations are ignored, making them mutually exclusive. Second, `__new__` is automatically a class method which is why implementing it must result in `__init__` and `__call__` being totally ignored. Here's how to implement it for the functionality I was needing:

```py
class MyClass:
  ...
  _phrase: str = None

  def __new__(cls, phrase: str=None) -> str:
    ...
    if phrase is not None:
      ...# Implement a custom initialization and update
      cls._phrase = phrase

    elif (cls._phrase, phrase) == (None, None): 
      ...# Implement a default initialization
      cls._phrase = "Hello, world!"

    # Do any necessary work here

    return cls._phrase

print(MyClass())                  # Prints "Hello, world!"
print(MyClass("Goodbye, y'all!")) # Prints "Goodbye, y'all!"
print(MyClass())                  # Prints "Goodbye, y'all!"
```

Essentially, one `__new__` class method can be used to do what `__init__` and `__call__` do for class instances.